# SilverStripe Fluent automatic translation behaviour

Tags: php, silverstripe

The SilverStripe Fluent mod seems to automatically translate all fields within a `DataExtension`. To disable this I had to use: `private static $translate = 'none';`.

Which is odd because when it comes to `DataObjects` it works the opposite way: nothing is translated automatically, only the fields you explicitly tell to be translated.

Is it possible to *disable* this automatic translation behaviour of the SS-Fluent mod? It would also be interesting to know what other stuff Fluent automatically translates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just building on Barry's answer; Fluent doesn't translate extensions, it translates DataObjects, and will by default automatically translate fields on the dataobject that match the `Fluent.data_include` rules. Think of it as extensions pushing fields into the dataobject itself, which fluent sees as being owned by that extended object, rather than the extension itself.

The issue you're running into is the automatic translate behaviour, where `translate` isn't defined. You can follow Barry's answer to solve this for individual objects.

If you want to globally disable all automatic field translations, you can copy the values from `Fluent.data_include` to `Fluent.data_exclude`. A field type in this list will not be include for localisation (even if in `Fluent.data_include`).

```
---
Name: myfluentconfig
After: '#fluentconfig'
---
Fluent:
  data_exclude:
    - 'Text'
    - 'Varchar'
    - 'HTMLText'
    - 'HTMLVarchar'
```

This means that if you have a dataobject (or extension) like below, it won't get automatically translated.

```
class MyObject extends DataObject {
    private static $db = [
        'Name' => 'Text'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the code...

In silverstripe any static array can be set in the code, so yes adding this to _confip.php

```
Config::inst()->update('MyDataObject', 'translate',<SET ME HERE>);
```

...will work making sure to set the required value!

If you want to add the same thing into config.yml then...

```
MyDataObject:
  translate:
    - 'FieldOne'
    - 'SomeOtherField'
```

...this is covered in more detail in https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/docs/en/configuration.md

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear on this. What I want to do is to stop the *Fluent* mod from automatically translating fields in a class that extends `DataExtension`

Comment: I think that is what I've answered, if you change 'MyDataObject' for 'AnyClassName' then this works for ANYTHING in silverstripe.  See silverstripe uses dev/build to compile all this information (which is why when you change it you need to dev build!) so the above code works for static variable in any class...please try it ok?

Comment: You're right, this does work as I expected! But I'm trying to find the root of the issue: Where in the config files of Fluent does it say that Fluent should automatically translate DataExtensions? If there is no answer to this, then your setup is the only way to go and I will tick it off as answer. Cheers

Comment: ok, well I' must have misunderstood "config file", I've updated to indicate how to do this in config.yml too

Comment: Thanks again for your input Barry. The current setup translates FieldOne and SomeOtherField. It doesn't disable automatic translation of fields in DataExtensions, which is my goal.

Comment: and you've tried 'none' instead of the yml format for an array?

Comment: That would probably work as well.. But again, I'm not trying to just fix this, I'm trying to find the root of the problem. The thing is, I don't understand that when you create a `DataObject` you have to specifically state which fields you would like to have translatable, but when you extend `DataExtension` all fields are made translatable by default.

Comment: ok, I'm going to leave this here because I feel I've answered and I'm not going to get any further.  Best of luck and talk to you again on your next question probably :)